# Loading a new view when the the user doe not have internet connection in webkit

Tags: xcode, swift, webkit

I have a web app that I'm loading in Webkit and as of now when the user doesn't have Internet connection an error message shows up with this code. I would like to make it so a whole new view shows up instead of just an error message.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError!) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new UIView and add it to your current ViewController:

```
var errorView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))

self.view.addSubview(errorView)
```

Comment: but how do I check if the user has internet connection or not?